# do i need a google voice number for setting up asterisk server?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, voip

I'm working on developing a modernised ring bell intercom system where the owner can call the visitor with his phone over the internet on the intercom (VoIP). and the first idea that came to me is to set up an Asterisk Sip server on Google App engine using this [tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/general/guide-setup-asterisk-server-google-t2126964) but I didn't understand the purpose of using a google voice number, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. The question as it is, will tend to generate opinion-based answers. Try stating your doubts in a more concise or concrete way.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, should I write a new message or edit this one

Comment: It's up to you. I'd edit this one.